# display a corresponding button and it's link in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, erb

I have a structured layout here in Rails 5 ERB that renders a partial for each data passed in as locals via a json file for data, but each of them either has 1 or 2 buttons with it's corresponding links inside, I also want to change the button's title for each link it corresponds to. I've already implemented it but I feel that putting all the logic in the view is kind of unappealing is there a way that i can put this in a helper that displays a specific button for each of their links inside of the json file?

I basically want to achieve this

[Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjWY6.jpg)

**data.json**

```
[{
  "github": "https://github.com/",
  "heroku": "https://heroku.com/",
  "button": [{"github": "github", "heroku": "heroku", "codepen": "codepen", "behance": "behance"}]
},
{
  "github": "https://github.com/",
  "heroku": "https://heroku.com/",
  "button": [{"github": "github", "heroku": "heroku", "codepen": "codepen", "behance": "behance"}]
},
{
  "codepen": "https://codepen.com/",
  "button": [{"github": "github", "heroku": "heroku", "codepen": "codepen", "behance": "behance"}]
},
{
  "codepen": "https://behance.com",
  "button": [{"github": "github", "heroku": "heroku", "codepen": "codepen", "behance": "behance"}]
}]
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
  def portfolio_section(title, &block)
    render(:partial => 'editable-sections/portfolio-section', 
    :locals => {:title => title, :block => block})
  end
```

**index.html.erb controller/template**

```
<%= portfolio_section('Portfolio') do %>
  <!-- nested partials -->
  <!--  Send data from our json file and pass in local variable for it to be interpolated  -->
  <% @data.each do |data| %>
      <%= render(:partial => 'editable-sections/panels/panel', :locals => {:data => data})%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**_panel.html.erb /partial**

```
  <!-- _panel.html.erb -->
   <div class="btn-position">
     <% if data["github"] && ["heroku"].present?%>
       <a href="<%= data["github"] %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sharp">
          <%= data["button"][0]["github"]%>
       </a>
       <a href="<%= data["heroku"] %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sharp">
         <%=data["button"][0]["heroku"] %>
       </a>
       <% elsif data["codepen"].present?%>
       <a href="<%= data["codepen"] %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sharp">
          <%= data["button"][0]["codepen"]%>
       </a>
       <% elsif data["behance"].present?%>
       <a href="<%= data["behance"] %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sharp">
          <%= data["button"][0]["behance"]%>
       </a>
     <% end %>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract login into your helper and pass and render the helper method. Like you can extract the first condition like this below.

```
def make github_link data
   link_to(data["github"] , data["button"][0]["github"] , class: "btn btn-sharp", target: '_blank') if data["github"] && ["heroku"].present?
end
```

and use this method into your partial. That should clean the view. If you want to go further you can use decorators https://github.com/drapergem/draper . For title, you can pass a parameter into a helper and change whatever you like. The helper can be more dynamic as well.

Comment: Thanks I've tried it, made a little configurations and It works, I might checkout draper too.

Comment: Can you accept the answer that will be awesome of you.